# argparse: determine if the value is default or entered by user

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-option', choices=['a','b','c'],type=str, default='a')
args = parser.parse_args(['-option','a'])
print(args)
```

resulting namespace object:

```
Namespace(option='a')
```

If I run the parse_args() without passing any argument I also get:

```
Namespace(option='a')
```

Is there a way to differentiate if the option was given by the user or it was set by the default value?

Comment: The purpose value if to get the value no matter if the user gives it or not. You may use another solution, remove the default, and add the logic in your python code later

Comment: Don't provide default value and test for `None`

Comment: What's the context - why do you need to differentiate?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I think this is the only way